# How to use TRIM to get value from serialised field

Tags: mysql, trim

I want to use TRIM in a Mysql query to get a number out of a serialised meta-value [wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value]. The text before and after the number are always consistent.

For the sake of arguement. the value is red39blue - I want to retrieve the number 39 - or whatever the number is.

In the select section of my large query i want something like -

```
TRIM(TRAILING 'blue' ( TRIM(LEADING 'red', wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value) ) )
```

Any help gratefully accepted :)

Comment: Do you mean literally `red39blue` in the field?

Comment: This is doable, but hideously complicated in SQL

Comment: yeah thats why im asking here ;) i have no choice as i cant alter the db

Comment: @tadman - no its not literally that, literally it's     a:1:{i:0;i:WIDGET;}       where WIDGET is what I want to retrieve - ie its a serialised array, maybe theres an SQL function to unserialise the array rather than using trim... I dunno ;(

Comment: That looks like it's been encoded with [PHP's `serialize` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) so why can't you just de-serialize it with [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)? A pure MySQL solution is going to be horrendously ugly. A PHP one is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` for this stuff:

```
replace(replace(wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value, 'red', ''), 'blue', '')
```

Comment: Thanks Kosh. I worked this out independantly so it was nice to come back here and see it was an OK approach. A bit hacky o/c. I think another way to do it would be to use a nested substring_index. The difficulty with what I needed to replace was the strings contained ; and other stuff. Not sure if I needed to but I converted the characters to decimal versions. The finished select was:  

REPLACE( REPLACE(jn_postmeta_persons.meta_value,CONCAT(CHAR(59),CHAR(125)),"") , CONCAT(CHAR(97),CHAR(58),CHAR(49),CHAR(58),CHAR(123),CHAR(105),CHAR(58),CHAR(48),CHAR(59),CHAR(105),CHAR(58)) , "" )

Comment: @Shaun, you might also try JSON methods if your mysql version supports them: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html